# @Html.RenderPartial does not have css appied to it from Master Layout?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a Master.cshtml layout which looks like the following:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <title></title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8" />

    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/compiled-styles.css">

    <script src="../scripts/modernizr.custom.67294.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

   @{Html.RenderPartial("MainNavigation");}

    @RenderBody()

    @{Html.RenderPartial("BottomNavigation");}

    <!-- Included JS Files (Compressed) -->



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../scripts/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The css from compiled-styles.css gets applied to the Master and it also gets applied to the MainNavigation and BottomNavigation partials, but inside another page (Products.cshtml), I have another Partial and it does not get applied there.  Here is the source for that:

```
@{
    Layout = "Master.cshtml";
}


<div id="products">
    <section id="products-filter-overlay">

        <button class="back-button">

            <svg width="76px" height="48px" viewBox="0 0 76 48" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:sketch="http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch/ns">
                <!-- Generator: Sketch 3.3.2 (12043) - http://www.bohemiancoding.com/sketch -->
                <title>Shape</title>
                <desc>Created with Sketch.</desc>
                <defs></defs>
                <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" sketch:type="MSPage">
                    <g id="Products-Filter-Overlay@2x" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup" transform="translate(-100.000000, -100.000000)" fill="#FFFFFF" opacity="0.8">
                        <path d="M172.709993,120.286477 L111.231928,120.286477 L125.901491,105.615964 C127.186638,104.331577 127.186638,102.248058 125.901491,100.96386 C124.616344,99.6787132 122.532825,99.6787132 121.249578,100.96386 L100.96386,121.249958 C99.6787132,122.534345 99.6787132,124.618054 100.96386,125.902061 L121.249578,146.189108 C121.891961,146.831872 122.733843,147.152778 123.575534,147.152778 C124.417226,147.152778 125.259107,146.831872 125.901491,146.189108 C127.186638,144.904721 127.186638,142.821202 125.901491,141.537195 L111.231928,126.865921 L172.709993,126.865921 C174.526755,126.865921 176,125.392866 176,123.576104 C176,121.759342 174.526945,120.286477 172.709993,120.286477 L172.709993,120.286477 Z" id="Shape" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup"></path>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>

        </button>


        <div class="module group">

            <h2>TELL US ABOUT YOUR VEHICLE</h2>

            <h3>So we can show you the products that can take it to the next level</h3>

            @{
                Html.RenderPartial("ProductFilter",new ProductFilterModel());
            }


            <a href="#" id="noVehicle" class="vehicle-not-found">I didn't find my vehicle</a>

            <a href="#" class="view-all-products">Skip this step and see all products</a>

        </div><!--module-->

    </section>
</div>
```

The css gets applied to everything in Products.cshtml, but the ProductFilter view doesn't get any of the css applied to it.  When I view the html, I can see the css link rendered at the top.  Here is my partial view:

```
@model ProductFilterModel

@using (@Html.BeginUmbracoForm("GetProducts", "ProductFilter", null, new { @class = "vehicle-filter-group" }))
{
    <div class="select">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Year, new List<SelectListItem>
    {
        new SelectListItem{Text = "YEAR", Value = ""},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "1990", Value = "1990"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "1991", Value = "1991"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "1992", Value = "1992"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text = "1993", Value = "1993"},
    }, new { @class = "year" })
    </div>

    <div class="select">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Year, new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "MAKE", Value = ""},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Volvo", Value = "Volvo"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Saab", Value = "Saab"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Opel", Value = "Opel"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Audi", Value = "Audi"},
        }, new { @class = "make" })
    </div>

    <div class="select">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Model, new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "MODEL", Value = ""},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Volvo", Value = "Volvo"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Saab", Value = "Saab"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Opel", Value = "Opel"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Audi", Value = "Audi"},
        }, new { @class = "model" })
    </div>


    <div class="select">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Engine, new List<SelectListItem>
        {
            new SelectListItem{Text = "ENGINE", Value = ""},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Volvo", Value = "Volvo"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Saab", Value = "Saab"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Opel", Value = "Opel"},
            new SelectListItem{ Text = "Audi", Value = "Audi"},
        }, new { @class = "model" })
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="search-button">SEARCH</button>
}
```

Comment: All of this information and code is nice, but in the end you need to show the generated HTML, and better yet a MCVE of the HTML & CSHTML's

Answer (score 0):

With `Html.RenderPartial()` you need to pass the Model you want to render as well.
ex `{Html.RenderPartial("Foo", Bar);}`